# Pass PHP variable created in one function to another

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I am using wordpress and woocommerce ( an e-commerce plugin) to customize a shopping cart. Within my functions.php I am storing data in a variable like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $newVar = $value['data']->price;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to use `$newVar` in a different function so I can echo the result on a different area of the page. For instance, if I had the following function, how would I use `$newVar` within it?

```
add_action( 'another_area', 'function_name' );

function function_name() {
    echo $newVar;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could make the variable global:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    global $newVar;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $newVar = $value['data']->price;
    }
}

function function_name() {
    global $newVar;
    echo $newVar;
}
```

Or, if `$newVar` is already available in the global scope you could do:

```
function function_name($newVar) {
    echo $newVar;
}

// Add the hook
add_action( 'another_area', 'function_name' );

// Trigger the hook with the $newVar;
do_action('another_area', $newVar);
```

Comment: does global $newVar need to be defined in the new function?

Comment: a simple question...why declare $newVar global, is `global` a bad practice?? and should be $newVar an array?is a really question to clear up my ideas

Comment: @JCHASE11 yes `global $newVar` needs to be defined in both functions. No it is not a bad practice, it is necessary to get the variables in the right scope. You could also use superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason why you can't call your function from within your foreach loop?

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $newVar = $value['data']->price;
        function_name($newVar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use return $variable in your functions:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
  foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    $newVar = $value['data']->price;
  }
  return $newVar;
}

function function_name($newVar) {
//do something with $newVar
}
```

And use like this:

```
$variable = add_custom_price( $cart_object );

$xxx = function_name($variable);
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking at what @ChunkyBaconPlz said $newVar should be an array:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
  foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    $newVar[] = $value['data']->price;
  }
  return $newVar;
}
```

Comment: This is assuming he wants to set `$newVar` multiple times, and then return only the last iteration of `$newVar` set by his `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

even if its defined global its not working while calling in other function how ever if we call function in other function it seems to be working.

```
<?php

function one() {
    global $newVar;

        $newVar = "hello";

}

function two() {
    one();
    global $newVar;

    echo $newVar;
}
 two();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. You need to instantiate (create) $newVar outside of the function first. Then it will be view-able by your other function.

You see, scope determines what objects can be seen other objects. If you create a variable within a function, it will only be usable from within that function. Once the function ends, that variable is eliminated!

So to fix, literally just create "$newVar" before you create the function and you should be good to go.

Comment: You still need to make the var `global`.